# Creating numerous ranges or blocks of folders/directories?

Tags: command-line, scripting, directory, numeric-data

[EDITED to reflect answers below]

I am looking for a way to create blocks of folders / directories from the command line or a script that will generate a top level folder titled "200000-209999" and then inside of that folder, sub-folders named thusly:

```
200000-200499
200500-200999
201000-201499
... etc ...
... etc ...
208500-208999
209000-209499
209500-209999
```

The naming is spaced like you see, and then I would want to set up the next batch of top-level/sub-folders, "210000-219999," "220000-229999," etc.

[EDIT]

I came up with the following script based on the answers below to accomplish exactly what I am looking for. My additions may not be elegant scripting, so if it can be improved upon,  let me know.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# mkfolders.sh
#
#    Ask user for starting range of job #'s and create the subsequent
#    folder hiearchy to contain them all.
#
###

clear
read -p 'Starting Job# in range: ' jobnum
mkdir "${jobnum}"-"$((jobnum + 9999))"
for start in $(seq $jobnum 500 $((jobnum+9999))); do mkdir "${jobnum}"-"$((jobnum + 9999))"/"${start}"-"$((start + 499))"; done
echo
echo Done!
echo
```

Comment: How far does "etc" go?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Incrementing by 500s?

Comment: to infinity...and beyond? how many directories do we want?

Comment: These are actually folders that will contain jobs, and a job folder might look like "208532 ACME Widget Co - Project Roadrunner". The number denotes the job number, and in the interest of organization, I'm looking to group these into lots of 500. Top-level folders will contain 10,000 job folders further organized into groups of 500 inside of sub-folders. I only plan on doing this in one grouping at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `seq` utility is one way to generate numbers:

```
for start in $(seq 200000 500 209000); do mkdir "${start}"-"$((start + 499))"; done
```

The syntax is `seq start increment end`.

Comment: Boom! This did exactly what I was looking for, thank you Jeff! Now I'll be playing around with a little interactiveness to it so I can just enter the range for the top-level folder and it will create that along with all the sub-folders inside in one fell swoop.

Answer (score 0):

The simple shell approach is this:

```
$ i=200000; while [ "$i" -ne 210000 ];do  echo ${i}-$((i+499)); i=$((i+500)); done
```

Replace `echo` with `mkdir` to create the actual folders. This loop should be executed in the directory where you intend to place the folders, so make sure you `cd` there first.

Comment: Thank you Sergiy! This gives me more to consider! Both of these solutions work great!

Comment: @CraigDaters Glad my answers help :)